# New tag: write18. What's the consensus?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I have to say that I don't like it.  It feels too specific.  The question in question is: [Is it possible to compile a *TeX document with a single command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3293/is-it-possible-to-compile-a-tex-document-with-a-single-command).  I think that in this case, there's no need for an extra tag.  In general, I'd like something a little more descriptive (though I'm having trouble thinking of one).

Answer (score 5):

It should either be "shell escape" or "write18". That's simply how it's referred to, and it's how you enable it on the command line: `-enable-write18` or `-shell-escape`.

I'm generally not in favour of being too prescriptive about what tags should be in use, although I'll concede that a tag for this idea won't be used too often.

So I think it's fine.

Comment: write18 is shorter and couldn't mean anything else.  You've convinced me that we should prefer [write18].

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer `shell-escape` and `write18` as synonym. Shell-escape is the correct technical term IMHO but people will often use the other one instead. The `filesystem-access` tag is more general and doesn't cut it IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

We already have `filesystem-access`, so how about `shell-access`?

Comment: Sounds good but then we need an alias because otherwise users will be really confused. The tag `[write18]` *seems* so innocuous.

Comment: What is "filesystem-access" supposed to mean?

Comment: Reading, writing and manipulating files, e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2375/file-input-and-output If you can come up with a better name (I don’t really like the current one) for that, please suggest a rename.

Comment: Hmmm, not easy, I agree. Something like `file-io` comes to mind but I don't know if that's any better.